# I can't configure og:title correctly

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I created an app with the follow metas:

```
<title>Nosotras</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Nosotras"/>
```

However, the activity feed shows "is ussing php-sdk". I tried to use the URL linter and i get a incorrect data (og:title: php-sdk) but "php-sdk" don't exist in any of the app files: [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://apps.facebook.com/nosotras-aecc/)

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

For apps.facebook.com urls the title is the title of your application I think.

Comment: The title and the og:title is "Nosotras" but appears "php-sdk"

Comment: Do you have more than 50 likes? Your title gets frozen if you have more than that.